# Import Error in Tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda installed in my computer. I have installed all modules of tensorflow in it. I am trying to import tensorflow from jupyter notebook , but i am getting following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Can anyone help me solve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an error of updating numpy library.

I upgraded numpy using folowing command,

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

and the problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the Traceback, the Import error is being raised because your current version of numpy is not compatible with Tensorflow. Updating the numpy package should fix this.

Try this in Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda update numpy
```

**Useful Links:**

- http://cs.franklin.edu/~ansaria/traceback.html
- https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-update.html